# Authorize.net : createcustomerprofilerequest : E00116 OTS Token access violation

Tags: authorize.net, cim

I am able to successfully manage customer profiles using the Accept.js and the API in the DEV / Sandbox environment, however when I moved the code to PROD, it failed with the error: E00116 OTS Token access violation.

Searching, I see that error E00116 can happen when the creds are wrong, eg., using DEV creds in PROD,  but I've double checked and believe that everything is fine there.

I am using our PROD creds successfully via Accept.js and the API when using createTransactionRequest.  There is another thread at https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/OTS-Token-Access-Violation/td-p...  which has the same error, however the user was unable to use the method in DEV as well.  That is not my situation, as everything works fine in DEV.

I've attempt to break this out into two different steps as well by creating the customerProfile first, then adding the paymentProfile.  The customerProfile is successfully created, however I receive the same error (in PROD only, DEV works fine) when creating the paymentProfile.

Any thoughts on what might be done to correct this?  Is it an internal AuthNet problem?  Could there be a setting in the PROD account that needs to be set?

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would make sure I am using the correct API credentials for the given environment (PROD Vs Sandbox). Secondly, I would check the capitalisation of the API credentials, mostly, the ApiLoginId, as it's case sensitive, and make sure you are using the correct casing (as issued in the Merchant Interface) across all your API requests.

Comment: Mansour, I appreciate your comment, however I am using the current values in another process (one time capture, via Accept) and they work fine with that process.  As you noted, I double checked capitalization and all appears to be correct, however continues not to work.